# Spreading gracefully buttons horizontally across a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

This is my very first post at Stackoverflow. Before I make my question, I just want to say that this is a great resource of information and I find the community extremely helpful.
I hope to be able to share my Android development knowledge with everyone else as well.

I have been developing for Android for 6 months now and, although I have learned very much, I still greatly struggle when it comes to layout/design.

I have one layout.xml file that contains a Relative layout. Inside this layout, I have three buttons. I want those three buttons to have a certain width size that would grow or shrink depending on the device's screen size/density.

This is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1123123213"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Earned" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin2"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="In Progress" />


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin3"
        android:layout_width="107dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnLogin2"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Done" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hard coded the width values, considering that I have different text sizes in each button... so that should obviously affect the width as well...

My question is... is there any intelligent way to accomplish this? Maybe programatically, when I know the current device's screen size?

Thanks everyone!
Felipe

====================================================
UPDATED SECTION

Hey guys,
Thanks for your help so far.

I have added the LinearLayout and the weight as per recommendation, but I am still not exactly getting what I want. It's almost there, but not quite.

My new xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_height"
android:orientation="horizontal"  
android:gravity="center" android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bottonbar_earned" 
        android:layout_weight=".10"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".10"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/bottonbar_inprogress" />


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/balloon_overlay_close"
        android:gravity="center" android:text="@string/bottonbar_redeemed"
        android:layout_weight=".90"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result [link](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg822/scaled.php?server=822&filename=47659084.png&res=medium)
Can you see the end of the right side? I don't think the weight is distributed like it should, although I set a .90 weight to the third button.
What do you guys think?

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is use `android:layout_weight` attribute on buttons, but you need to place them into a `LinearLayout`.  If you need to have `RelativeLayout`, then you can place the `LinearLayout` inside it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >
    <Button
        android:text="left" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".30" /> 

    <Button
        android:text="center" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".40" />

    <Button
        android:text="right" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".30" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you could do it in xml itself, I wouldn't recommend doing it programmatically. You can add something like  :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  
    android:gravity="center" style="android:style/ButtonBar" >
      <Button android:text="Ok" android:id="@+id/bookOkBtn"
              android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

      <Button android:text="Return" android:id="@+id/bookReturnBtn" 
             android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_weight="1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Making android:layout_width="0" & android:layout_weight=1 uses all the available space width wise.

If you want height-wise also, then specify dip in `android:layout_height="100dip"` and check your desired height.

If this also doesn't fit your needs and dynamic setting is only the solution, then have added Answer for that too.

**UPDATED :** 
Have a look at this code :

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="horizontal"  android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_marginTop="15dp" style="android:style/ButtonBar">
    <Button android:id="@+id/browseAddBtn" android:text="Add" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/browseViewBtn" android:text="Edit" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"  />
    <Button android:id="@+id/browseDelBtn" android:text="Delete" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"  />
    <Button android:id="@+id/browseReturnBtn" android:text="Return" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />        
</LinearLayout>
```

RESULTS [image: Click Here]

Image shows results of above code and also on changing the layout_weight as mentioned in file respectively. My parent layout is also LinearLayout & has no padding or margins set.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: thank you for giving me your time to help me out.
I tried again and no luck. this is the [screenshot](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg821/scaled.php?server=821&filename=screenshot2012020321525.png&res=medium) from my phone. It doesn't stretch at all!
Here is the scenario: I have my main.xml which main element is a RelativeLayout. There, I invoke my bottom bar, inside a LinearLayout.

Comment: The code for inside the RelativeLayout is
`<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout20"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           >

            <com.nuvemdepontos.widget.BottomActionBar
                android:id="@+id/bottomactionbar"
                style="@style/BottomActionBar">
            </com.nuvemdepontos.widget.BottomActionBar>
        </LinearLayout>`

Comment: @FelipeCaldas, I have added all applicable code in the dynamic solution Answer. Prior to that, Remove all the styles and see, remove weight sum & see. Copy the LinearLayout in another new xml with parent also as LinearLayout. I strongly recommend to try solving in xml itself. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like a case for a `LinearLayout` than a `RelativeLayout`. If you specify a `LinearLayout` as the parent with a total layout weight of 3 and have each of your `Buttons` specify a layout weight of 1 they should end up precisely as you desire on any screen.

Answer (score 1):

I had same situation where I had to set sizes of buttons based on screen sizes and density. I calculate the size of buttons based on the actual space for the application I get.

I would suggest you to use LinearLAyout instead of RelativeLayout, but as you have some experience, you must be aware of the differences and ease of usage with Linear rather than Relative layouts.

In my XML I have root LinearLayout & 2 inner LinearLayout (row1 & row2). Each row has 3 butttons.
In my onCreate I get above 3 of them using findViewById.

Using the LayoutParams and the screen's size and densty, I calcualte the size of buttons and text sizes. 
Algorithm :

1. Get Screen height & Width
2. Deduct the padding & margins you use
3. Deduct height of Title bar
4. Now, you have got your full available space. Divide it horizontally & vertically as you need
5. This will give you size of 1 button
6. Set the same size to all buttons
7. Based on buttons width & height & density figure out the text size

You can start up with this, if you need help I will be there. Feel free to ask.

**UPDATED : CODE ADDED :-**

These methods are added in a class named "Utility" and made static to access the methods in whole project easily :

```
      public static ScreenInfo scrnInfo = new ScreenInfo();

public static void calculateChildSize(LinearLayout root, LinearLayout.LayoutParams row1Params, LinearLayout.LayoutParams row2Params, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height, width;
    int childWidth, childHeight;

    //gets screen dimensions 
    height = metrics.heightPixels;  //480
    width = metrics.widthPixels;    //320
    scrnInfo.setScreenHeight(height);
    scrnInfo.setScreenWidth(width);

    //Log.i("MY", "Actual Screen Height = " + height + " Width = " + width);
    // Get height/width after deducting Padding of all 4 sides
    height = height - (root.getPaddingBottom() + root.getPaddingTop()); // 480-70
    width = width - (root.getPaddingLeft() + root.getPaddingRight());   // 320-70
    //Log.i(TAG, "Actual Area after Padding W = " + width + " H = " + height);

    int bottomMargin = row1Params.bottomMargin; //15
    bottomMargin = (row1Params.bottomMargin %2) == 0 ? row1Params.bottomMargin : row1Params.bottomMargin+1;

    // Actual Height/Width of child
    childWidth = (int)(width);
    childHeight = (int)(height /2) - (bottomMargin/2);  

    childHeight -= scrnInfo.getTitleBarHeight();    
    scrnInfo.setRowHeight(childHeight);

    row1Params.height = childHeight;
    row1Params.width = childWidth;
    row1Params.bottomMargin = (bottomMargin/2);

    row2Params.height = childHeight;
    row2Params.width = childWidth;
    row2Params.topMargin = (bottomMargin/2);

    scrnInfo.setChild1LayoutParams(row1Params);
    scrnInfo.setChild2LayoutParams(row2Params);

    calcTileWidthHeight(childWidth);
    calcTileTextSize();
    //android.util.Log.i(TAG, "Child W = " + childWidth + " H = " + childHeight + " Tile W = " + scrnInfo.getTileWidth() + " Tile Text Size = " + getTileTextSize());

    return;
}

public static void calcTileWidthHeight(int childWidth) {
    int margin = 8;
    scrnInfo.setTileWidth(((childWidth/3)-margin));
}

public static void findTitleBarHeight(Window win) {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    win.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    int statusHeight = rect.top;
    int contentViewTop = win.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
    int titleHeight = contentViewTop - statusHeight;

    scrnInfo.setTitleBarHeight(titleHeight);    // SET TitleBarHeight
    //Log.i(Utility.TAG, "titleHeight = " + titleHeight + " statusHeight = " + statusHeight + " contentViewTop = " + contentViewTop);

    return;
}

public static void calcTileTextSize() {
    // current is 11 on W = 75 => its small
    int w = scrnInfo.getTileWidth();
    float ts = 11f;

    if (w >= 51 && w <= 70) // Port LDPI W - 54 H -98
        ts = 15f;
    // Screen 320 * 480 Medium dense
    else if (w >= 71 && w <= 80)    // Port MDPI 
        ts = 13f;
    else if (w >= 81 && w <= 110)   // Land LDPI W - 81 H - 58
        ts = 15f;
    else if (w >= 111 && w <= 220)  // Landscape - Perfect
        ts = 18f;
    else if (w >= 221 && w <= 250)
        ts = 20f;
    setTileTextSize(ts);        
}
```

***ScreenInfo class contains setters/getters for following members :***

```
public class ScreenInfo {
private int titleBarHeight, screenHeight, screenWidth;
private int rowHeight;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams child1LayoutParams, child2LayoutParams;
private int _6tiles_Width;  // Width of a Tile where 3 tiles on 2rows r shown
```

***NOW comes actual implementation in Activity :***

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.datapage);

   root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dataroot);
   row1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.datarow1); 
   row2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.datarow2);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.relationBtn);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.productBtn);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bankBtn);
    btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locationBtn);
    btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.curencyBtn);
    btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dataReturnBtn);       

    root.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Utility.findTitleBarHeight(getWindow());

            // CALCULATE THE SIZE OF INNER LAYOUTS
            //calculateChildSize();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams row1Params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) row1.getLayoutParams();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams row2Params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) row2.getLayoutParams();

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            Utility.calculateChildSize(root, row1Params, row2Params, metrics);

            row1.setLayoutParams(Utility.scrnInfo.getChild1LayoutParams());
            row2.setLayoutParams(Utility.scrnInfo.getChild2LayoutParams());

            RefreshComponents();
        }
    });             
}

protected void RefreshComponents() {
    // Set background of the root 
    root.setBackgroundColor(Utility.getBackgroundColor());
    // set Gradient Colors & text color of all buttons
    RefreshGradientButtons();
}

protected void RefreshGradientButtons() {
    GradientDrawable btnGradient = Utility.getButtonDrawable(); 
    int i = -1;
    for(i=0; i < row1.getChildCount(); i++) {
        Button btn = (Button)row1.getChildAt(i);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(btnGradient);
        btn.setTextColor(Utility.getTextColor());
        btn.setTextSize(Utility.getTileTextSize());
    }

    for(i=0; i < row2.getChildCount(); i++) {
        Button btn = (Button)row2.getChildAt(i);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(btnGradient);
        btn.setTextColor(Utility.getTextColor());
        btn.setTextSize(Utility.getTileTextSize());
    }       
}
```

Whenever screen is changed from Portrait to Landscape or vice-versa OR if at all density is changed at runtime, onCeate is called every such time. Hence this code is added in onCreate(), so the calculations and settings can be appropriately on spot.

In my app, this works like a charm in versions from 1.5 to 3.2 and all density's.

You will have to make changes for your requirement accordingly. As your design is just 3 buttons in a row, while my design for the above code is like Tiles on screen. 2 rows n 3 buttons in each row. I have kept the logs I had added as it will help you to debug and figure out your solution.

This will work 100%.

*I would still recommend to give a try to : just create a new xml and in LinearLayout as parent, add your LinearLayout of buttons and see. Does that work ? While executing try it in both the modes. In your LinearLayout try removing weightSum. According to me, this requirement should be achieved in xml itself. *

BEST LUCK.

Comment: Hey guys,
Thanks for your help so far.

I have added the LinearLayout and the weight as per recommendation, but I am still not exactly getting what I want. It's almost there, but not quite.

Comment: Can you update the xml and show the results in your question. And show what's still missing. Based on that, will be able to help you out.

Comment: Sorry, I am going to do that now :)

Comment: @FelipeCaldas, Remove gravity="center" from each button and make weight of all as "1". And see the difference.

Comment: @FelipeCaldas, OR make the weight come total to "100". Your's at present is 110. Make it 100 and see teh difference. I think this should do the work.

Comment: I set the LinearLayout weight to 100 and first button to 5, second to 5 and third to 90. Feels a bit better, but not 100%... there still a bit of room in the right side... I feel I will only be able to accomplish this programatically!
Any chances you could give me a code snippet of the code that made you reach that goal?
Thanks a ton

Comment: I just checked the solution in my Samsung Galaxy Nexus. Pretty bad
There's enough room in the right side for a whole car :-)
The background is a 9 patch, so it's stretching alright.
But the components widths are not

Comment: @FelipeCaldas, I can share the code - no probs at all. But your task is very simple and straight forward. You can achieve it thru xml itself. I discourage for code, just b'coz it executes every time onCreate executes. Try making 1st 2 btns as "10" & last as "75" leaving little space for spare. IMP : I beleive the parent layouts don't have any paddings/margins set. AS that could be affecting. If still doesn't work, show the new result image again.

Comment: again, thank you so much for this piece of code. I sure will test later on tonight!
It's strange that it's not stretching like it should... in my emulator, using API 8 it works great
Now, when I bring the app to my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, it almost stretches ok... but still not 100%! 
Will let you know soon about my accomplishments :)